# The time complexity of a recursive algorithm

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

How do I determine the time complexity of this recursive algorithm?

```
void func(int n){
    count++;
    if (n == 0) {
    return;
    }
    if (n <= 1000) {
       func(n-1);
       func(n-1);
    } 
    else {
       func(n-1);
       func(n-1);
       func(n-1);
    }
}
```

This should be fairly simple (Is it theta(2^n) ?) but I'm not sure and I don't know how to prove it. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be f(n) is O(3^n) (because you need to consider asymptotic bounds).

Consider looking up the master theorem for more insight on how to analyze the run-time of recursive functions.

Comment: Won't it be instead O(5^n), with recurrence relation T(n) = 3T(n-1) + 2T(n-1) + 1, if n > 1000?

Comment: Consider this code, it is functionally equivalent to yours:

`void func(int n){
    count++;
    if (n == 0) {
      return;
    }
    func(n-1);
    func(n-1);
    if (n > 1000) {
       func(n-1);
    } 
}`

Hopefully this will illustrate why the branching factor is 3.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thank you ~